# Tuleap (full) installation error yum Dependency Error (php-launcher.sh)

Tags: installation, centos, dependencies, tuleap

Trying to install the latest version, but it seems to be broken:

`yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras tuleap-all`

```
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/share/codendi/src/utils/php-launcher.sh for package: tuleap-plugin-git-4.85-1.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: tuleap-plugin-git-4.85-1.el6.noarch (Tuleap)
       Requires: /usr/share/codendi/src/utils/php-launcher.sh
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodiges
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're following the guide available at:

http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html

> In [rpmforge] section replace set enabled = 0

The RPMFORGE repository must be disabled *after* the installation.
Try to install with the enabled parameter set to 1.